# Execute a function after changing location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function after redirecting the page.

Inside my function I put a parameter which is an ID but when I check the console it wont display. I know I can be able to run it via on click event but I wont get the ID param from the previous page.

Is there a way to get it done?

Code:

```
function encode(item_id){
  $('.js-encode').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    location.href = url; // new url
    save(item_id); // call function after new url finish loading
  });
}

function save(item_id){
  console.log(item_id); // check if there's item_id exists
}
```

Comment: because you are redirected in another page. The javascripts in the previous page will not be applied to the new page

Comment: Is there a way to get it?

Comment: You need to call save first, then do redirect.

Comment: add it as query string, for example 'http://newlocation.com?id=' + item_id +

Comment: All code below this line `location.href = url` is not executing at all because as soon as this line executes, new page starts to load. It's same as if you enter this URL in browser manually.

Comment: Yeah I checked it. After page load all codes below that line wont execute

Comment: do as @Katana said or alternatively save it in localstorage and retrieve it from there on next page but this too will work only if the both url has same base address.

Comment: I get your point guys but how can I call a function after that?

Comment: @RuslanStelmachenko So does the function return or exit early, once `location.href = url` is executed? The JS stops on that page essentially?

Comment: @Qwerty yes, JS virtual machine stops execution and browser starts to load new URL. I don't know how it is implemented internally in the JS VM, though.

Comment: @RuslanStelmachenko Interestingly enough, I was able to `setTimeout(console.log, 200, 'hi')` and still see the output in dev tools in some cases. It seems it is [not halted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247829/what-happens-in-the-browser-after-location-href-is-changed) after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Katana's comment. Anything after your redirect statement will not run because the page itself is redirecting. One way that I would suggest to still get the item_id and get around that barrier, would be to include the item_id in the redirect url as a parameter. Then once on the new page, parse that parameter out of the url and save the item_id.

A great example from [Cory Laviska's article on Parsing URLs in Javascript](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/parsing-urls-in-javascript/), shows how you can get the individual parameters from a URL.

Building onto [Manish' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37716277/5220880):

**Function on the current page:**

```
function encode(item_id){
    $('.js-encode').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    location.href = url+'?saved_item_id='+item_id; // new url
    });
}
```

**Function on the REDIRECTED Page** (assuming you only have one parameter)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var url = $(this).data('url');
     var item_id = url.queryKey['saved_item_id'];
     save(item_id);
 });
```

It may need a few tweeks because I didn't test the code, but hopefully it'll get you on the right track. :)

**Hopefully this helps. If it helps and/or answers your question, please select as answer and up vote! :D Feel free to let me know if you have any questions**

Comment: Thanks for the effort but how can I load save function after the redirect?

Comment: Updated code to include functions for both pages. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

The container is the section of your page where you perform an action.

```
function encode(item_id){
  $('.js-encode').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $("#container").load(url,function(){
        // other stuffs and functionalities
         save(item_id); // call function after new url finish loading
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Can I pass info from that loaded URL back up to the top level function?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
function encode(item_id){
  $('.js-encode').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    location.href = url+'?saved_item_id='+item_id; // new url
    //save(item_id); // call function after new url finish loading
  });
}

/*(function save(item_id){
  console.log(item_id); // check if there's item_id exists
}*/
```

Further more , On New redirected URL you can get item_id which was appended to URL in previous page.

Hope this may help.

Comment: I get your point here but how can I call a function after the page loaded? I wanted to call the function after the redirect happened

Comment: You can check for saved_item_id for blank or `typeof(saved_item_id) != 'undefined'` If that saved_item_id is not blank or exists, You can just call your function. :-)