# Do some code after jquery redirect

Tags: javascript

I have question. For example, using jquery I open site. The code `location.href = "https://somesite.com";` . Can I delete some element from site or add some element to site from script after this code `location.href = "https://somesite.com";` after redirect?

Comment: dupes:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048338/how-can-i-execute-a-script-after-calling-window-location-href | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716183/execute-a-function-after-changing-location-href

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a function after changing location.href](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716183/execute-a-function-after-changing-location-href)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute a script after calling window.location.href?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048338/how-can-i-execute-a-script-after-calling-window-location-href)

Answer (score -2):

No. When the browser left the page using `location.href = 'XYZ'` your code is unloaded at all. Also, the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) should prevent what you want to do.

You could write a plugin for your web browser to achieve your goal.

Comment: -1 - this is an obvious dupe; try not to encourage this by answering. You haven't really given an answer to the question other than saying "no".  You have left "enter link description here" as the link text.

Comment: Fixed the link :-)