# On location.href redirect to # parameter execute code

Tags: javascript, dom, redirect, href, onload

This question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716183/execute-a-function-after-changing-location-href), but my redirect is to the same page, but a #parameterhere. For example I am in example.com and the location.href changes to example.com/#1 and then example.com/#2 and so on as time goes.

I wrote this function:

```
window.onload = function () {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
};
```

But it does not execute because the DOM is not reloaded... How do I execute this code after the internal URL changes?

Comment: you should add `eventListener` and check this question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onhashchange` event handler ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)):

```js
window.onhashchange = function () {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
};
```